# Reverse for 'cart_detail' not found. 'cart_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-views

Here is my Add to Cart button HTML:`

```
<a href="{% url 'store:add_cart' product_detail.id %}"> </a>
```

Here is my add_cart view:

```
 def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            cart_id=_cart_id(request)
        )
        cart.save()

    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
        cart_item.quantity += 1
        cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product=product,
            quantity=1,
            cart=cart,
        )
        cart_item.save()

    return redirect('cart_detail')
```

And here's my urls.py for add_cart and cart_detail:

```
 app_name = 'store'

    urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('product-list/', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('cart/', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    path('cart/add/<int:product_id>', views.add_cart, name='add_cart'),
    path('detail/<slug:product_slug>', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('category/<slug:category_slug>', views.home, name='products_by_category'),
    ]
```

When I click on add to cart button in my product-detail page:

I GET THIS ERROR: Reverse for 'cart_detail' not found. 'cart_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Which points to my view add_property -> return redirect('cart_detail')

I tried changing my 'cart_detail' to '/cart' in the views but then it's showing that my cart has no items even though the model objects Cart and Cart Item are created.

PLEASE HELP RESOLVE ASAP[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMAde.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B6Sw.png)

Comment: try using
return redirect(reverse('cart_detail')) and if /cart don't show any then the error might be at your cart_detail view function

Comment: Thank you for reaching out! I tried using reverse but it did not work
This is my cart_detail view function:
def cart_detail(request, total=0, counter=0, cart_items=None):
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, is_active=True)
        for cart_item in cart_items:
            total += (cart_item.product.discounted_price * cart_item.quantity)
            counter += cart_item.quantity
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass

Comment: contd...
    template = 'store/cart.html'
    context = {
        "cart_items": cart_items,
        "total": total,
        "counter": counter,
    }
    return render(request, template)

Comment: Fixed context also while rendering cart_detail but still showing the same error